# multiple emplace_back calling copy constructor additionally

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, emplace

Consider the below example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class S {
public:
  S() { puts("S()"); }
  S(int) { puts("S(int)"); }
  ~S() { puts("~S()"); }
  S(const S &) { puts("S(const S&)"); }
  S(S &&) { puts("S&&"); }
  const S &operator=(const S &s) {
    puts("=");
    return s;
  }
  S &operator=(S &&s) {
    puts("Move =");
    return s;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<S> s;
  s.emplace_back();
  s.emplace_back(6);
}
```

O/p :

```
S()
S(int)
S(const S&)
~S()
~S()
~S()
```

When only one element is `emplaced_back`, the `constructor/destructor pair` are called exactly once. But when there are multiple `emplace_back` (like `s.emplace_back(6);`), the `copy constructor` is also called. Why is this behavior difference ? is there still a copy exists with emplace_back ?

Answer (score 3):

Take into account that `std::vector` sometimes enlarges it's allocated area (when you add to many elements) and must copy old values over to new positions. This cause the call of the copy constructor.

You can call `reserve()`

```
std::vector<S> s;
s.reserve(20);
s.emplace_back();
s.emplace_back(6);
```

to say the `s` vector has to reserve a larger memory area to avoid relocations of elements.

Comment: Shouldn't it use the move constructor when resizing?

Comment: @TobySpeight The move constructor is only allowed to be called if it's marked as `noexcept`.

Comment: Ah, yes; I'd forgotten that.

Comment: @TobySpeight - good question; see the comment from Sombrero Chicken and the answer from Liliscent for an answer (and I confess I didn't know it).

Comment: @SombreroChicken - thanks for the edit-correction :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is because reallocation happens as explained by @max66. As for why it is the copy constructor being called, it is because your move constructor is not `noexcept`.

Change to this:

```
S(S &&) noexcept { puts("S&&"); }
```

Then it's the move constructor being called.

Comment: I am not seeing any difference in terms of construction with adding `noexcept` to move ctor (without `reserve`). Only the copy constructor is replaced with the move constructor.

Comment: @Sitesh nothrow_move_constructible is the requirement for calling move constructor in `std::vector` reallocation.